# App Reject By ios App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, libgdx

I am using `libgdx` to create an ios app. I checked the sdk that is is compiling with, and it is 7.0.2.  How do I fix this?

> 1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
>     /var/folders/cj/t7129jm93gv3pj_wjdfjq2qm0000gn/T/834524929.itmsp -
>   Error Messages:
>        Apple's web service operation was not
>   successful
>         Unable to authenticate the package:
>   834524929.itmsp
>        ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with
>   public (GM) versions of Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK. Do not submit apps
>   built with beta software." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset
>   (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
>          Could not start delivery: all
>   transports failed diagnostics

Comment: you're using a beta version of Xcode.

Comment: I have the same problem. I Compile using FDT (actionscript) and iOS 7. I do not have any beta software. I have XCode 5.0.2 from appstore.

Answer (score 5):

> This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App
>   Store must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 5 and iOS 7
>   SDK. Do not submit apps built with beta software.

Let's look at this part carefully:

> Must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 5 and iOS 7
>   SDK. Do not submit apps built with beta software.

Zoom in a bit, please?

> Do not submit apps built with beta software.

You are using the Xcode developer preview, probably Xcode 5.1 for iOS 7.1 beta. Since this iOS version is not out, Apple does not allow you to submit apps compiled under this version of Xcode, hence your bundle is "invalid".

Simply open up Xcode with this project, fix any errors that may come, recompile and submit.

Comment: How do I add a robovm project to xcode? It is in eclipse right now.

Comment: Keep in mind, this is a java project. Also I have Xcode 5.0.2 with iOS 7.