# Xcode appstore submission issue "must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK"

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore-approval

I'm using XCode 5.1 (5B130a) that I got from the mac appstore. I'm compiling an app and when I submit it to the store, I get this error :

"New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK"

Comment: I think, you need to update your Xcode. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04252014a

Comment: look at here.. same issue  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22186426/3615320

Comment: possible duplicate of [The bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with public](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695688/the-bundle-is-invalid-new-apps-and-app-updates-submitted-to-the-app-store-must)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update XCode to the last version.
Also that 'b' in `5B130a release` means that you are in BETA Version of `XCode`

Also the Apple Guidelines say:

> Do not submit apps built with beta software

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but i am using this version xcode6 beta4 and ios8.

When i have submit app that time below error is occurs:

Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 SDK or later. Don’t submit apps built with beta software.