# XCode 8 GM Seed - Error while uploading to TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, seed, gm

While Uploading the .ipa file (Generated using Xcode GM Seed) into TestFlight, I am receiving the following error.

> **ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at 'Payload/Application.app/Assets.car' can't be read. Try rebuilding the
>   app with a non-beta version of Xcode and submit it again."**
>
> DBG-X: The error code is: 1102

Did anyone get across similar issue?

Comment: Refer this link may be useful. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186386/app-reject-by-ios-app-store

Comment: I've same problem. Did you use previously Xcode 8 Beta?

Answer (score 8):

1) Double check and make sure you are building with Xcode 8 GM Seed.
2) Make sure you are using latest version of El Cap.
3) Delete ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder.(It was my issue)
4) Rebuild project.
Make sure environment you are submitting from is also running Latest El Cap and Xcode 8 GM.

If you working with multiple version of Xcode (i.e. 7.3.1 & 8.0 or higher), make sure you launch **Application Loader** from **respective Xcode version**. If you build an IPA file from Xcode 8.0, open Application loader from that **Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader**.

Good luck!

Comment: This line fixed it for me: Make sure environment you are submitting from is also running Latest El Cap and Xcode 8 GM

Answer (score 3):

I had this warning just now and it turned out to be completely false - the actual issue was that I was using Application Loader v3.5 to submit an application that had been written in Xcode 8. So if nothing else works, ensure that you either use the Archive screen to upload your build from the version of Xcode upon which the archive was created, or else open Application Loader from the correct version of Xcode by selecting `Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader`

Answer (score 3):

I had two XCodes on my Mac, 7.3 and 8.1. I made the archive using 8.1 but was uploading it with Xcode 7.3 Application Loader (3.5). Uploading with Xcode 8.1 Application Loader (3.6) resolved the issue for me
**Don't worry about OSx version**

Answer (score 2):

We also had this failure when using an older version of Application Loader.  Updating Application Loader (3.0 -> 3.6) fixed the problem.  The app being uploaded was built with Xcode 8.0, we had not seen this problem with Xcode 7.x-built apps.

Comment: I was also on the sierra 10.12.1, the failed attempt may have come from an older version of the OS, so I would not count out the OS-upgrade solutions that others are reporting.  Basically:  Upgrade the uploader toolset, there is some boundary there that you need to cross over for Xcode 8.x built apps to upload correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue last Friday while uploading the build using Application Loader. I was using the Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a) and mac OS Version 10.11.5 (15F34).

In my system I have two Xcode (v7.3 and 8.0). Xcode 7.3 was using Application Loader 3.5 while Xcode 8.0 was using Application Loader 3.6

When I open the Application Loader app through Spotlight search it opens Application Loader 3.5 which led to the above error.

Rather I had to explicitly open Application Loader 3.6 (Xcode > Open Developer Tools > Application Loader) which is the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple versions of Xcode on your machine then this problem occurs. Launch the Application Loader app from the Xcode itself using Open Developer Tool Dock menu item or from the Xcode main menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I downloaded the newly released production version of Xcode via the App Store app and resubmitted using that version and it submitted successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was resolved for me by upgrading to the production version of macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

We have been receiving the same error from itunesconnect.apple.com when trying to upload a new ipa created using Xcode 8.0 (8A218a) macOS Sierra 10.12. We tried every solution we could find while waiting for Apple support to respond and nothing worked. This included creating builds with 8.x deployment targets and 9.x deployment targets.

Apple support finally responded that the issue was due to 2 images created using the P3 display gamut, which didn’t make much sense since the error response for that issue is usually ERROR ITMS-90682 Assets.car can’t contain 16-bit or P3 assets if the app supports iOS 8 or earlier.

We updated the 2 images they flagged and tried to upload again and we received the same error message about having used a beta version of Xcode.

We finally found a solution by using Xcode to upload the build to the app store instead of the website and it worked!

Apparently there is a bug with itunesconnect.apple.com, which misidentifies builds created using Xcode 8 as being created with a beta version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue. Need to upload the build with xCode 8.0+ and application loader v3.6